# JavaScript, Submit button check if an input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, submit, dom-manipulation, is-empty

I have a form that places a user's inputs onto the DOM, as well as removing them. The issue is if someone presses the remove button when no inputs are logged onto the DOM it will throw an error to the console. I attempted an **IF** statement but it doesn't work, The code which I have used is: `(h6_w ===  "" || h6_w == null) { return false; }.`

The error which the console is throwing is: `app.js:210 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement. <anonymous(app.js:210)`

```js
// Delete From The Dom.
const delBtn = document.querySelector('.del-btn');

delBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 // Remove Form Input.
  let h6_w = document.querySelectorAll('.h6_weight_class');
  // Empty String.
  if (h6_w ===  "" || h6_w == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
  // Remove Child
    h6_w[h6_w.length - 1].remove();
  };
});


// Add User's input To The Dom.
const addDom = document.querySelector('.add-dom');
const wForm = document.querySelector('.weight-form');
  
wForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

   // Get Input Value.
   const value = wForm.querySelector('input[type="number"]').value;
   const value1 = wForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;

   // Create Elements.
   const h6_weight = document.createElement('h6');

   // Adding Id.
   h6_weight.classList.add('h6_weight_class');

   // Add Content.
   h6_weight.textContent = value + value1;

   // Append To Dom.
   addDom.appendChild(h6_weight);
   
  });
```

Comment: ```document.querySelectorAll``` returns an empty nodeList if there are no inputs.
it will not be equal to "" or null. Change your if statement to ```if (!h6_w.length)```

Comment: if you log this `h6_w[h6_w.length - 1]` what is the output?

Comment: Nir Shabi that has worked :) thanks :) :)